# Android PreferenceScreen Title Bar remove

Tags: android, settings, preferenceactivity

I want to get rid of top title bar in preference activity and all child screens.
Problem i am facing right now does not occur on jelly bean but on older versions.
If i cant remove it, i would like to change it behaviour so title in child screen does not get transferred from list item.

I did not set anything to title in this screen, text properties was copied by system from parent screen. Title on parent screen has been set by setTitle() on root preferencecategory. Problem exists on 2.3.6

[image]

[image]

Comment: upload your AndroidManifest.xml code.

Comment: you want to set full screen for a single screen or for all the activity ?

Comment: this is fullscreen app, i want to get rid of this blue one with "settings", and overlaped "particles"

Comment: but your AndroidManifest.xml code says only one Activity, WallpaperSettings has Full Scree mode

Comment: both screens are wallpapersettings activity, and manifest says that there are four fullscreens activity, and everything with being fullscreen is ok, this is not window preference related problem.

Comment: can you post the xml from which you are inflating this preference?

Comment: There is no such file, all preferences are added programmatically, but i dont think layout has anything to do in this case, its quite simple, when you have preferencescreen witch has childs, its main title became  header in screen witch its childs, and header is being copied 1:1 from title field of preference

Comment: there is short version of code : http://pastebin.com/Uv3Sp3dY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, this issue has been fixed on the more recent Android releases. It is caused by a bug where nested preferences were hardcoded to always use either the internal `Theme` or `Theme_NoTitleBar` from the framework. The [commit that fixed the bug](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/72e6bece43ca2778d8101a6d4dede2a12e0d47e8) was apparently merged sometime after the Gingerbread release.

The easiest way to workaround this bug (just to get rid of the unwanted title text) is to add an `onPreferenceClickListener` to your `PreferenceScreen` object and set the title to null. For the code that you posted, this is how it would look like:

```
    particleSettings.setLayoutResource(R.layout.iconpreferencee);
    particleSettings.setKey("screen_preference");
    particleSettings.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("" + "Particles" + ""));
    particleSettings.setSummary(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#7c71d8\">"
            + "Count , type , color , size, gitter ... " + "</font>"));
    // workaround for Android bug 5351628
    particleSettings.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
            new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
                    final PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) pref;
                    screen.getDialog().setTitle(null);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this in the AndroidManifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: its already set, both bars on this screens arent titlebars from activity, i mean those are titlebars with category name from preference screen, when i touch particles, on second screenshot, screen from first screenshot apperars, and its title its transferred from name on first list, and its transferred with all text properties. I am using setTitle( Html.fromHtml("some text and tags")) to set font and color of elements on list, and this whole html is transferred from "Title" position in list element layout to header in child screen.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

**Create each Preference as a separate XML and a separate Activity!** This will prevent this kind of properties to be inherited.

You can then call child preference from parent preference like this:

```
<Preference
    android:key="TODO"
    android:title="@string/TODO"
    android:summary="@string/TODO"
>
    <intent
        android:action="com.example.project.preference.child1" />
</Preference>
```

And your child preference should have that same action defined on Manifest

```
<action android:name="com.example.project.preference.child1" />
```

Make sure **com.example.project.preference.child1** is unique!

Now, on values/styles.xml, add this:

```
<style name="app_theme_no_title_pref" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Of course, you can change *android:Theme.Light* to whatever you need.

On Manifest, add this to all Preferences Activity, parent and children:

```
android:theme="@style/app_theme_no_title_pref"
```

So, in your Manifest your child preference Activity should look like this:

```
<activity android:name=".TODO"
    android:label="@string/TODO"
    android:theme="@style/app_theme_no_title_pref">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.project.preference.child1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this in your java file:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try first remove title: Add a super class, Like (for example):

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends Activity
```

In FullScreenActivity, add method:

```
    private void addFlags() {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    this.getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


    Log.d(TAG, "add flags");
}
```

And call this method onCreate of FullScreenActivity

So...

You can do your activity and all of subclasses maybe a FullScreen by flags.

```
public class MyActivity extends FullScreenActivity
```

Try this to test solve... and you can setTitle for every Activity (if not, use a super class title).